# Tracing lambda expression evaluation

Tags: lambda, scheme, sicp, operator-precedence, interpreted-language

I am having trouble with some tricky-looking lambda expressions in Scheme, and I would like to see how they are being evaluated by the interpreter.

I would like the Scheme interpreter to print all the evaluation steps, as seen in [SICP Section 1.1.5, "The Substitution Model for Procedure Application"](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.5).

I am looking for a solution using any Scheme interpreter. I have already tried [Racket's tracing](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/debugging.html#%28mod-path._racket%2Ftrace%29), but it only traces procedure calls, not every expression.

**Motivating example**

Given the definition of Church numerals from [SICP Exercise 2.6](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%_thm_2.6):

```
(define zero (lambda (f) (lambda (x) x)))

(define (add-1 n)
  (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f ((n f) x)))))
```

and the task:

> Define `one` and `two` directly (not in terms of `zero` and `add-1`).

I wish to check my definitions of `one` and `two` against the results of evaluating `(add-1 zero)` and `(add-1 (add-1 zero))`.

This is what I would like the Scheme interpreter to print out:

```
> (add-1 zero)
(add-1 (lambda (f) (lambda (x) x)))
(lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f (((lambda (f) (lambda (x) x)) f) x))))
(lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f ((lambda (x) x) x))))
(lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f x)))
>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790241/scheme-expand-procedure-calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy with combinators-like equations (what [was once called *applicative style* I believe](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0521277248) )

```
zero f x = x
add1 n f x = f (n f x)

one f x = add1 zero f x = f (zero f x) = f x         **(1)**
two f x = add1 one f x = f (one f x) = f (f x)       **(2)**
```

With combinators, everything is curried: `a b c d` is actually `(((a b) c) d)` and `a b c = d` is equivalent to `(define a (lambda (b) (lambda (c) d)))`.

Now it is clear what is the intended meaning of `f` and `x`: `x` stands for a concrete implementation of "zero" data element, and `f` stands for a concrete implementation of "successor" operation, compatible with a given concrete implementation of "zero". `f` and `x` should have really be named mnemonically:

```
zero s z = z
add1 n s z = s (n s z)
```

Not so tricky-looking anymore, with more convenient syntax, right? `lambda` itself was a typographical accident anyway. Now,

```
one s z = s z         ; e.g. (1+ 0)
two s z = s (s z)     ; e.g. (1+ (1+ 0))
```

---

Tracing the steps according to the [SICP 1.1.3 combinations evaluation](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.3) procedure,

- To evaluate a combination, do the following:

  1. Evaluate the subexpressions of the combination.
  2. Apply the procedure that is the value of the leftmost subexpression (the operator) to the arguments that are the values of the other subexpressions (the operands).

and the [1.1.5 sustitution model for procedure application](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.5)

- To apply a compound procedure to arguments, evaluate the body of the procedure with each formal parameter replaced by the corresponding argument.

we get

```
add1 zero = 
  ( n f x => f (n f x) ) ( f x => x ) =
  ( f x => f ( ( f x => x ) f x ) )
```

and here the substitution stops actually, because the result is a simple lambda expression, i.e. not a combination. Only when two more arguments are supplied, the evaluation is done in full:

```
add1 zero s z = 
  ( n f x => f (n f x) ) ( f x => x ) s z =
  ( f x => f ( ( f x => x ) f x ) ) s z =
  ( x => {s} ( ( f x => x ) {s} x ) ) z =    ; {s} is definition-of s
  {s} ( ( f x => x ) {s} {z} ) =             ; {z} is definition-of z
  ; must find the value of the operand in combination
  {s} ( ( x => x ) {z} ) = 
  {s} {z}
```

and then the calculation will proceed according to the actual definitions of `s` and `z`. That is what the equations **(1)** shown above indicate, in shorter notation.

Answer (score 2):

Give Racket's built-in stepper a try, there's a little how-to in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14657535/201359).