# let loop code in Racket. Recursive factorial

Tags: loops, racket

Consider:

```
(define (factorial x)
  (let loop ((x x)
             (acc 1))
    (if (zero? x)
        acc
        (loop (sub1 x) (* x acc)))))
```

I dont understand how does work let here. Moreover, I dont understand this code.

Answer (score 6):

Your example works the same as

```
(define (factorial x)
  (define (loop x acc)
    (if (zero? x)
        acc
        (loop (sub1 x) (* x acc))))
   (loop x 1))
```

which works the same as

```
  (define (factorial x)
    (loop x 1))

  (define (loop x acc)
    (if (zero? x)
        acc
        (loop (sub1 x) (* x acc))))
```

To see how the program works, the best advice is to use the stepper in DrRacket.
Since the stepper must be run in the "Intermediate" teaching language, paste this version (note the final example) into DrRacket. Choose the "Intermediate" teaching language and click the stepper button.

```
(define (factorial x)
  (loop x 1))

(define (loop x acc)
  (if (zero? x)
      acc
      (loop (sub1 x) (* x acc))))

(factorial 3)
```

See also this question for an image that shows the stepper: [Fibonacci in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14657325/23567)

Comment: I think you may have posted the wrong image link? I don't see the stepper in that image.

Comment: @stchang You are right. I have inserted a different link.