# Recursion confusion with multiple return

Tags: java, recursion

I'm still wrapping my mind around recursion, and I think I get basic ones like factorial.  But I'd like further clarification when the return statement is a little more complex like on the following snippet:

```
/**
 * @param n >= 0
 * @return the nth Fibonacci number 
 */
public static int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return 1; // base cases
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2); // recursive step
    }
}
```

In the return statement, does the fibonacci(n-1) completely recur through, before going down the fibonacci(n-2) step (does that make sense)?  If so, this seems very difficult to envision.

Comment: If it's difficult to envision, just step through your code with a debugger. That will show you *exactly* what's happening.

Comment: With the assumption the above is single threaded, yes.

Comment: The order of `fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);` is unspecified, either may execute first

Comment: You can also do it on paper. Try with n = 4, that's just a few steps.

Comment: Yes, recursion always goes deep. It helps to work it with a small number and work out the return at each stage.

Comment: This question is not even remotely related to the duplicate, which is about implementation-defined order of calls. Voting to re-open.

Comment: public static  smells JAVA

Comment: This changed in C++11, I think, and the linked duplicate doesn’t make the details clear. One will finish being called before the other starts, but it isn’t specified which will happen first.

Comment: Even though it's tagged Scheme, the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14673510/434551 clearly explains what happens in your function.

Comment: Ok, you say it's actually Java not broken C++. Then remove the wrong tag too Did that for you now.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, one invocation will recurse all the way down and return, before the other one starts executing.

The order of invocation in Java is well-defined: `fibonacci(n-1)` goes before `fibonacci(n-2)`.

**Edit:** Since the question originally included [C++] tag, here is the C++ part of the story: one of the two invocations still has to complete before the other one starts to run, but which one, `fibonacci(n-1)` or `fibonacci(n-2)`, is unspecified.

Since the function has no side effects, it does not matter which of the two invocations gets to run first. The only thing that is important for understanding of recursion is that both invocations must complete, and their results must be added together, before the invocation at the current level returns.

Comment: You should probably edit your answer now that the C++ tag has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't much more different than calling a different function than itself.  It needs to finish before the calling function can do anything with the result.

```
finobacci(0); // ==> 1 (since n is zero, the base case is to return 1)
fibonacci(1); // ==> 1 (since n is one, the base case is to return 1)
```

Now lets try `2` which is not the base case:

```
fibonacci(2);                // == (since it's not the base case)
fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0); // == (both calls to fibonacci we already haver done above)
1 + 1                        // ==> 2
```

So in reality what happens is that the call to fibonacci2 waits while each of the two recursive calls to **finish**, just like a function that does `System.out.println` would wait until it had printed the argument before continuing to the next line. Recursion isn't that special.

Trivia: This is the original series from Fibonacci himself. Modern mathematicians start the series with `n` as the base case result making the series `0, 1, 1, 2, ...` rather than `1, 1, 2, 3, ...`.

Comment: @Hulk Corrected the comment.

Answer (score 0):

it works in this way:

**Fibonacci program**:

```
public int fibonacci(int n)  {
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(n == 1)
      return 1;
   else
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

**Explanation:**
In fibonacci sequence each item is the sum of the previous two. So, as per recursive algorithm.

So,

```
fibonacci(5) = fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)

fibonacci(3) = fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)

fibonacci(4) = fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2)

fibonacci(2) = fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0)
```

Now you already know `fibonacci(1)==1 and fibonacci(0) == 0`. So, you can subsequently calculate the other values.

Now,

```
fibonacci(2) = 1+0 = 1
fibonacci(3) = 1+1 = 2
fibonacci(4) = 2+1 = 3
fibonacci(5) = 3+2 = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In multiple recursion the program calls itself with its first call until the base case is reached, in this case **fibonacci(n-1)**; after that the recursion stops and return his value to continue calling the value to the second part of the recursion **fibonacci(n-2)**.

If you don't visualize the multiple recursion in the program, this 
[fibonacci recursion tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQQfm.gif) may be helpful.